# Hide buttons until viewed in mobile in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap to style my website. I am using the nabber styles and the collapse styles. In my site I have a navbar at the top that contains three buttons, Home, Online Giving, Times & Locations. These are what I call "quick access links". Down the page I have the main links that are used to access the other pages of my site. I want to use the collapse style of bootstrap to collapse the links when viewed on a mobile website so that all the links are accessible from the toggle button on the navbar and hide the main links that are within my page and move them to the navbar at the top. I'm not sure if I'm making any sense. Below is my code.

```
<!-- Quick Navs -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse quick-nav" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Home</a>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#" target="_blank">ONLINE GIVING</a></li>
            <li><a href="/whoweare">TIMES & LOCATION</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>


<div class="container header">
    <div class="inner-header">
        <p class="logo"><a href="/"><img src="/assets/images/fplogo-2.png" alt="logo"></a></p>

        <nav class="navbar primary-nav" role="navigation">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="/nextsteps">Next Steps</a></li>
                <li><a href="/events">Events</a></li>
                <li><a href="/ministries">Ministries</a></li>
                <li><a href="/whoweare">Who We Are</a></li>
                <li><a href="/listen">Listen</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have time to finish this answer right now, but on the off-chance that you are working on this right now, this example I made should give you a starting point: http://www.bootply.com/XDmIiKUJFx

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

*here you can change* **class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left">**

```
 <div class="container header">
    <div class="inner-header">
    <p class="logo"><a href="/"><img src="/assets/images/fplogo-2.png" alt="logo">  </a></p>

    <p class="visible-xs visible-sm ">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="offcanvas"><i
                        class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></button>
     </p>

      <nav class="navbar primary-nav hidden-xs hidden-sm" role="navigation" id="mobile_menu">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="/nextsteps">Next Steps</a></li>
        <li><a href="/events">Events</a></li>
        <li><a href="/ministries">Ministries</a></li>
        <li><a href="/whoweare">Who We Are</a></li>
        <li><a href="/listen">Listen</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

Js:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('[data-toggle=offcanvas]').click(function() {
        $('#mobile_menu').toggleClass('active');
      });
    });
```